# Filtering variables with a key value in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following data structure in ansible

```
hosts:
  host-1:
    roles: [ 'master' ]
    index_ip: 2
    outline: false
  host-2:
    roles: [ 'backend' ]
    index_ip: 3
    outline: false
  host-3:
    roles: [ 'frontend' ]
    index_ip: 4
    outline: false
  host-4:
    roles: [ 'frontend' ]
    index_ip: 5
    outline: false
```

I need to get a list  of hosts depending on the roles of the host.

Example:
Get the hosts with roles 'master' which should result in  [ 'host-1' ]

Example:
Get the hosts with roles 'frontend' which should result in [ 'host-3', 'host-4' ]

I am new to ansible and find this difficult to do. Any easy way of filtering this?

The data is used to generate starturp files that will spawn processes over several hosts.
Example:

```
central_supervisor:
  - hostlist: [ host-1 ]
    corelist: [ 0 ]

subsystem:
  - hostlist: [ host-2 ]
    sa_corelist: [0]
    app_corelist: [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]

data_router:
  - hostlist: [ host-3, host-4 ]
    corelist_e: [16]
    corelist_c: [15,31]

data_processor:
  - hostlist: [ host-3, host-4 ]
    capabilities: all
    corelist_e: [16]
    corelist_c: [15,31]
```

Comment: I don't get what you want. How many hosts are in the play, just 1, or 5?
If so, do you want each host to be aware of another hosts' role? Describe your end-goal, preferably w examples.

Comment: => `{{ hosts | selectattr('roles', 'contains', 'master') | dict2items | map(attribute='key') }}`. Now to add up to Kevin's comment, this definitely looks like an [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info) and a lack of knowledge about ansible inventories/groups/variables for groups and hosts, which you can start to fill by reading the [relevant documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: Actually the data structure is a variable defined in the roles/default/main.yml . It is not an inventory file but is used to create startup files for a simulator that will spawn over a number of masters, backends and frontends depending on configuration. Startup files are generated using jinja templates. I am afraid the selectattr fails

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "dict2items requires a dictionary, got <type 'generator'> instead."}

Answer (score 0):

I have made it in my jinja2 code instead

```
{% set frontends = [] %}
{% for hostname in item.hosts.keys() if 'frontend' in item.hosts[hostname].roles %}
   {{ frontends.append(hostname) }}
{% endfor %}
```